# Kendo ui grid inline date edit, passing date from Kendo UI to ASP.NET causes invalid ModelState

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I have a nullable DateTime property in my DataSource - ExpectedReceiptDate, and i'm implementing inline editing in the grid:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: {
         transport: { 
            //setup transport
        },
         schema:
         {
             data: 'Data', total: 'Total', errors: 'Errors',
             model:
             {
                 id: 'Id',
                 fields: {
                     Id : { editable: false, type: 'number' },
                     Name : { editable: false, type: 'string' },
                     ExpectedReceiptDate : { 
                        editable: true, 
                        format: "{0: dd/MMM/yyyy}",
                        nullable: true,
                        type: 'date'
                    }
                 }
             }
         },
         requestEnd: function(e) {
             if (e.type == 'update') {this.read();}
         },
         serverFiltering: true,
         serverSorting: true
     },
     editable: {
         mode: "inline"
     },
     columns: [
     {
         field: "Id",
         title: "ID"                                
     },{
         field: "Name",
         title: "Name"
     },{
         field: "ExpectedReceiptDate",
         title: "Date",
         editor: DateEditor, 
     },
     {
         title: "&nbsp;",
         command: ["edit"],
         width: 200
     }
     ]
 });
```

});

the editor is simple:

```
function DateEditor(container, options) {
                         $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                            .appendTo(container)
                             .kendoDatePicker({format: "dd/MMM/yyyy"});
                      }
```

when editing the row picking up the date for example 24/Feb/2017 i got an error:

*Invalid model state ExpectedReceiptDate, the value '(date) FLE Standard Time' is not valid for ExpectedReceiptDate*

I have tried to add custom validation for that field:

```
function ExpectedReceiptDateValidator(input){                       
                        if (input.is("[name='ExpectedReceiptDate']") && input.val() != "") {
                            try { 
                                var date = kendo.parseDate(input.val(), "dd/MMM/yyyy");
                                if(!date) 
                                    return false;                                   
                            } catch (err) { return false;}                          
                            console.log('res', true);
                        }                           
                        return true;
                    }
```

The validation passes, the entered date value is parsed well into Date obj, but model state error is still there. 
What causes the model state error?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the format specifier from the schema.model definition to the column definition as format isn't a configuration option of datasource.schema.model but is of grid.columns(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.format), which kind of makes sense as date format *is* a presentation concern.

With the format specifier on the column, you will not need the custom editor as the built-in date editor will use the format from the column configuration automatically.  You would only need the custom editor if you want to do some additional customization that is not standard.

Also, I'm not sure the "this.read()" call in the requestEnd is required.

Demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/oNOja

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the error with invalid model state was a Server's response, i didn't notice that and thought it was a client side issue. 
But anyway the issue with inline date edit was still there, finally i found an answer here:

[Passing dates from Kendo UI to ASP.NET MVC](https://blog.falafel.com/passing-dates-kendo-ui-aspnet/)

> MVC uses the “/Date(…)/” format when mapping JSON parameters, but not when mapping form data. By default, Kendo passes the parameters as a form.
>
> One way to handle this date parsing issue is to have the Kendo UI
>   DataSource send JSON data to the server instead of form data. Then MVC
>   will properly convert “/Date(…)/” to a DateTime automatically.
>
> The alternative to sending JSON formatted data is to leave our data as
>   form data, which is the default, and instead just change the
>   formatting of our dates.

So i did the following:

```
transport:{
  update: ..,
  parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
                if (operation === "update") {
                    data.ExpectedReceiptDate = formatDate(data.ExpectedReceiptDate);
                }
                return data;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the below worked for me as the Link is broken and couldn't find any working solutions out there.

So... in my case(well the only way I could get it to work), I have a change function on one of my grid fields (moving away from a physical save button #AutoSaveIsTheFuture)

```
 schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    errors: "Errors",
                    model: {
                        
                        fields: {
                            ...
                            ItemDate: { editable: true, type: "date", validation: { required: true }},
                            ...
                            Amount: { editable: true, type: "decimal", validation: { required: true }}
                        }
                    }
                },
```

...

```
 columns: [{
...

                    {
                        field: "ItemDate",
                        title: "Item Date",
                        format: "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}",
},
                        field: "Amount",
                        title: "Amount",
                        format: "{0:n2}",
                        editor: customAmountEditor
                        
                    }],
```

...

```
function customAmountEditor(container, options)
        {
            $('<input data-text-field="' + options.field + '" data-value-field="' + options.field + '" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" data-format="' + options.format + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoNumericTextBox({
                    change: SaveLineItem 
                    
                });
        }
```

that sends the fields to my Controller via AJAX POST method, in which I do the following :

```
 function SaveLineItem(e)
    {
        var element = e.sender.element;
        var row = element.closest("tr");
        var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

        var dateField = row.find("input[name='ItemDate']");
        var dateValue = dateField.val();

 $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName"))",
             data: {
                 "Id": dataItem.Id,
                 "ItemDateString": dateValue,
                ...
                "Amount": dataItem.Amount,
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                AddRow();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 410) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            }
         });
    }
```

It is received as a String on the Controller side , but at least its in the correct format ("yyyy/mm/dd") and easy to Convert using Convert.ToDateTime(ItemDateString);

Hope this helps. (Apologies if it's Messy)